# Implementing Sum Function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to solve a puzzle which takes 'n' arguments and then computes sum.

```js
function add(arg1) {
    let total=arg1;
    const func = function(...args){
        if(!args[0]) return total;
        total += args[0];
        return func;
    }

    return func;
}

console.log(add(1)(2)(3)()); // => Should output 6
```

**Question:** Using the same logic above example, I am trying to do this:

> What if I want to do something like
>
> sum(1)(2)(3) => should give 6
>
> If i do sum(1) => Should output 1
>
> sum(1)(2) => should output 3 and so
>   forth.

This is what I've tried:

```js
function sum2(num) {
    let total = num;

    const fn = function(...args) {
        if(args[0]) total += args[0];
        return total;
    }

    return fn();
}

console.log(sum2(1)) //=> Works
console.log(sum2(1)(2))// => Fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation:

[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) : The Proxy object is used to define custom behaviour for fundamental operations. In javascript you can create traps for pretty much every operation

- Used Getter function of the handler to return Sum
- Used Apply function of the handler to iterate and perform addition.

```js
function sum2(n) {
  sum = n;
  const adhoc = new Proxy(function a () {}, {
    get (obj, key) {
      return () => sum;
    },
    apply (receiver, ...args) {
      sum += args[1][0];
      return adhoc;
    },
  });
  return adhoc
}
console.log(sum2(1));
console.log(sum2(1)(2));
console.log(sum2(1)(2)(3));
```